# Having more lines of code in project will decrease the efficiency in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have my pojo class with getters and setters which can be replaced by single `@Data` annotation.

1. Likewise with some ways I reduce the number of lines will it connected with the efficiency of program ?
2. what is the scope(singleton or prototype) of objects created using `@Servive` or `@Repository`.
3. when to use `@Autowired` to access functions of other classes rather than `static` methods.

Can I use `static` methods to access function rather than `@Autowired` throughout my app, since `@Autowired`. will increase the application weight ?

Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

**1. I have my pojo class with getters and setters which can be replaced by single @Data annotation.
Likewise with some ways I reduce the number of lines will it connected with the efficiency of program ?**

The `@data` annotation will only hide the lines of code for you in your IDE. During compilation `projekt lombok` will generate java bytcode, so the number of lines of code wont change.

**2. what is the scope(singleton or prototype) of objects created using @servive or @repository.**

Default in Spring is `Singleton`

Reference spring docs:

> The Spring container validates the configuration of each bean as the container is created. However, the bean properties themselves are not set until the bean is actually created. Beans that are singleton-scoped and set to be pre-instantiated (the default) are created when the container is created

[Beans Resolution Process](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-dependency-resolution)

**3. When to use @autowired to access functions of other classes rather than static methods. Can I use static methods to access function rather than @autowired throughout my app, since @autowired will increase the application weight?**

You are comparing `@Autowire` with static methods. It's a wrong way of comparing. What you should be comparing is, `Singletons` compared to `static classes and variables` and this has already been answered [static-variable-vs-singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514623/static-variable-vs-singleton)

`@Autowire` has nothing to do with the fact that it is a singleton. The autowire functionality can be configured to produce new beans (prototypes) etc. `@Autowire` is to solve the [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) problem.

All these questions seem to be related to optimization from your part. Always remember [Premature optimization is the root to all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)