# Cache class - Need design suggestion

Tags: c#, caching, design-patterns, static, singleton

We're building a simple cache to be used across our web application.

The first instinct is use a static variable to hold the cache.

```
public class SimpleCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    //This is .NET's in-memory Cache
    private static MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions()); 

    public void Add<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        _cache.Set(key, value);
    }

    public bool Contains(string key)
    {
        return _cache.Get(key) != null;
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        _cache.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value)
    {
        return _cache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
}
```

1. Would you prefer to hold the cache as a static variable or would you choose to have a singleton instance for the class. Is there any advantage of choosing one over the other?
2. How does IDisposable work in static vs singleton scenario? Would there be any advantage w.r.t garbage collection while choosing one over the other?

Any guidance welcome.

Comment: 1. pretty opinion-based, 2. far too broad.

Comment: For 1. see this (although in Java, but you get the concept): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514623/static-variable-vs-singleton

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've updated the question to make it a bit more specific.

Comment: 1. DIing in an interface registered as singleton - the advantage is unit testability. 2. Short answer - no difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is just personal preference mind you.
I'd prefer to register the cache and have it passed into the SimpleCacheProvider as a dependency. That makes it easier to unit test.
As for IDisposable of statics, they aren't normally disposed of unless you do so manually.

```cs
public interface ICacheStore: IMemoryCache {}

public class SimpleCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    private readonly ICacheStore _cache;
    public SimpleCacheProvider(ICacheStore cache) => _cache = cache;
}
```

And then register a singleton instance of ICacheStore.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question. There is no great way to dispose static fields. You could do it during teardown of the application, but there is no guarantee that this will not be the first usage, and you may create the object just to dispose it again. I usually recommend avoiding any mutable static objects if possible, especially ones that need disposal.

Singletons can mean a few different things. It might just be a wrapper around a static field, and the above will apply. If a dependency injection container is used the "uniqueness" and lifetime of the singleton is usually tied to the  the container object. I find this preferable since you should have a well defined lifetime of the container object.